# Regarding storing attributes in a table

Tags: database

I need to create a database for a fictional bookstore. 2 of the attributes of the book entity are the author's first name and the author's last name. However, some books may have more than 1 author.

(The primary key for a book is the ISBN number)

My stupid question is this: Should I create an AUTHORS table that has a foreign key of the ISBN number or is there a different way I should be going about this?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Yes, that's the usual way (authors table, FK ISBN ... or maybe some additional shorter identifier instead of a lengthy ISBN-No., but I guess you're not after optimization here).

Comment: One step further would be, to have an authors table and a join table authors_books which associates and author to a book (n:m). But that depends on your actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You Should create an AUTHORS table that has a foreign key of the ISBN number
Because the relationship between **BOOK** and **AUTHOR** is one to many.
so you should create **AUTHORS** Table to maintain the good structure of your data base.